# How to set window name for a child window opened in inapp browser for hybridapp?

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app, inappbrowser

We have a requirement to open an external url in a inapp browser. we need to provide a name to child window since the external site we are opening validates the window name in javascript. If it is not as expected, it will clear the DOM. 
We tried opening the window using window.open(url,childWindowName). This is not setting the window name in iPhone/Andriod devices. Please help to achieve in setting window name to the child window.

Tried using an anchor tag with target as desired name. It is working but there is no option to go back to app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried  a workaround and it is working.

write a html file which will set the desired window name as below.

```
<head><script>window.name="myWindow"</script></head>
```

Then load this html file using window.open and change the child window location.

```
 var win = window.open('myHtml.html','_blank');
    function reload(){
    win.removeEventListener("loadstop", reload);
     win.executeScript({ code: "window.location.href="+desiredPath+";" });
    }
    win.addEventListener("loadstop", reload);
```